# Why does parseFloat(value) of form text input give NaN?

Tags: javascript

This returns NaN in the browser alert:

```
var in1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input1').value);
var form = document.getElementById('formC');

form.addEventListener('submit', function() {
    alert(in1);
});
```

However this works:

```
var form = document.getElementById('formC');

form.addEventListener('submit', function() {
    var in1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input1').value);
    alert(in1);
});
```

Could someone explain whats going on here? From the error it looks like "in1" is outside the scope of the 'function()' block however doesn't "var" make it global?

The html part:

```
<form id="formC">
    <input type="text" id="input1">
</form>
```

Comment: i would bet the first one fires before the input is filled-in by the user.

Comment: _"however doesn't "var" make it global?"_ Nope. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#Description

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because in the first example, you are attempting to get the value of the input and parse the float out of it immediately (before the user has had a chance to enter any data into it). So, trying to parse a float out of an empty string will yield `NaN`.

But in the second, you wait until the form is submitted to get the data, which is after the user has entered some data into the input.

> On page render the text field is blank.

Yes, and that is when this runs:

```
var in1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input1').value);
```

and sets the value of `in1` to `NaN`.

> But in both cases I manually type a number (5 or 3) into the text
>   field before clicking the submit button.

In the first case, it doesn't matter what you do because the variable `in1` already has its value. It's too late, that line has already been executed. You have no code that updates it to use the number you entered.

In the second case, it works because the variable isn't attempting to get the value until you've submitted the form, which is after you entered some data in the input field.

Comment: In both cases there was a number in the text field.

Comment: @ReinForce You are entering data after `in1` has gone and worked out the value, which was blank when it ran. Then, when you entered data and submitted the form, it didn't use the new data, it continued to use the old value from before you entered anything.

Comment: aaaah, I get it now. Getting the value and parse have both already run at the time the page loaded. I need to declare it "inside" the on-submit handler. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

When the page is rendered I am assuming there is no value in the input. And you already calculated the value of it and just using on submit.

But in the second case you are reading the live value of the input

Comment: On page render the text field is blank. But in both cases I manually type a number (5 or 3) into the text field before clicking the submit button.

Comment: @ReinForce See my comment above. Your explanation just reinforces what I'm saying.

Answer (score 0):

Sushanth -- and Scott Marcus are correct, you can verify by making following changes in your code

```
var form = document.getElementById('formC');
var in1 = document.getElementById('input1');

form.addEventListener('submit', function() {
    alert(parseFloat(in1.value));
});
```

as you can see `in1` is accessible inside the function, you just need to read the value once you submit, not before.
Above code should not return `NaN` unless provide invalid float number.